# Issue with a foreach loop WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have made theme with a custom posttype called 'Projects', with a few taxonomies, the one that matters with this bug is called 'Directors', or director_cat.

I have a page-template that goes trough each term in this taxonomy, and posts a thumbnail generated by an ACF field, that gets a Vimeo embed + a Vimeo stored thumbnail.

And then I made a slider for each "term", or Director if you will; with 7 of these Directors. The problem I found is that I get issues and PHP errors with the foreach loop, and the site moved really slow, on the load. I'm sure there is something wrong with my loop or a way to better make my code for sure, and I'm looking for some help to make this go trough faster, so the load times can be improved. In an ideal world, I would have the client upload his own thumbnails, but for now, the client isn't interested in that, so I have to solve the issue.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Related code underneath:

page-directors.php (a template for displaying a custom archive for the taxonomy 'directors'.

```
<section class="sider" id="reels">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">

                <?php
                // your taxonomy name
                $tax = 'director_cat';

                // get the terms of taxonomy
                $terms = get_terms( $tax, $args = array(
                  // 'hide_empty' => false, // do not hide empty terms
                ));

                // loop through all terms
                foreach( $terms as $term ) : ?>

                    <?php $term_link = get_term_link( $term );?>

                    <a href="<?php echo $term_link; ?>" class="director">
                        <p><?php echo $term->name; ?></p>
                        <div class="filter"></div>
                        <ul class="owl-carousel owl-theme director-reels">
                            <?php
                                $args = array(
                                    'post_type' => 'projects',
                                    'posts_per_page' => 7,
                                    'tax_query' => array(
                                        array(
                                            'taxonomy' => 'director_cat',
                                            'field' => 'slug',
                                            'terms' => $term->slug,
                                        )
                                    )
                            );
                            $posts = new WP_Query($args);

                            if( $posts->have_posts() ): while( $posts->have_posts() ) : $posts->the_post(); ?>

                                <li class="project"><img src="<?php echo get_field('project_thumb'); ?>" class="img-responsive" /></li>

                            <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
                        </ul>
                        </a>

                <?php endforeach; ?>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

opt-projects.php - Where I register the custom post-type and taxonomies.

```
<?php
/*--------------------------------------------------------------
  Registering Custom Post-Type for Projects
--------------------------------------------------------------*/

function project_post_type() {

  $labels = array(
    'name'                => _x( 'Projects', 'propipe' ),
    'singular_name'       => _x( 'Project', 'propipe' ),
    'menu_name'           => __( 'Projects', 'propipe' ),
    'all_items'           => __( 'All Projects', 'propipe' ),
    'view_item'           => __( 'View Project', 'propipe' ),
    'add_new_item'        => __( 'Add New Project', 'propipe' ),
    'add_new'             => __( 'Add New', 'propipe' ),
    'edit_item'           => __( 'Edit Project', 'propipe' ),
    'update_item'         => __( 'Update Project', 'propipe' ),
    'search_items'        => __( 'Search Projects', 'propipe' ),
    'not_found'           => __( 'Not found', 'propipe' ),
    'not_found_in_trash'  => __( 'Not found in trash', 'propipe' ),
  );
  $args = array(
    'label'               => __( 'Project', 'propipe' ),
    'description'         => __( 'Project Description', 'propipe' ),
    'labels'              => $labels,
    'supports'            => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'page-attributes', 'revisions' ),
    'taxonomies'          => false,
    'hierarchical'        => false,
    'public'              => true,
    'show_ui'             => true,
    'menu_icon'           => 'dashicons-video-alt3',
    'show_in_menu'        => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
    'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
    'menu_position'       => 20,
    'can_export'          => true,
    'has_archive'         => true,
    'exclude_from_search' => false,
    'query_var'           => true,
    'publicly_queryable'  => true,
    'capability_type'     => 'page',
  );
  register_post_type( 'projects', $args );

}

// Hook into the 'init' action
add_action( 'init', 'project_post_type', 0 );


/*--------------------------------------------------------------
  Registering Custom Taxonomy for Projects (films)
--------------------------------------------------------------*/

function films_cat() {

  $labels = array(
    'name'                       => _x( 'Film Types', 'motionblur' ),
    'singular_name'              => _x( 'Film Type', 'motionblur' ),
    'menu_name'                  => __( 'Film Types', 'motionblur' ),
    'all_items'                  => __( 'All Items', 'motionblur' ),
    'parent_item'                => __( 'Parent Item', 'motionblur' ),
    'parent_item_colon'          => __( 'Parent Item:', 'motionblur' ),
    'new_item_name'              => __( 'New Item Name', 'motionblur' ),
    'add_new_item'               => __( 'Add New Item', 'motionblur' ),
    'edit_item'                  => __( 'Edit Item', 'motionblur' ),
    'update_item'                => __( 'Update Item', 'motionblur' ),
    'separate_items_with_commas' => __( 'Separate items with commas', 'motionblur' ),
    'search_items'               => __( 'Search Items', 'motionblur' ),
    'add_or_remove_items'        => __( 'Add or remove items', 'motionblur' ),
    'choose_from_most_used'      => __( 'Choose from the most used items', 'motionblur' ),
    'not_found'                  => __( 'Not Found', 'motionblur' ),
  );
  $args = array(
    'labels'                     => $labels,
    'hierarchical'               => true,
    'public'                     => true,
    'show_ui'                    => true,
  'rewrite'                    => array('slug' => 'type', 'with_front' => false),
    'show_admin_column'          => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus'          => true,
    'show_tagcloud'              => true,
  );
  register_taxonomy( 'film_cat', array( 'projects' ), $args );

}

// Hook into the 'init' action
add_action( 'init', 'films_cat', 0 );


/*--------------------------------------------------------------
  Registering Custom Taxonomy for Projects (directors)
--------------------------------------------------------------*/

function directors_cat() {

  $labels = array(
    'name'                       => _x( 'Directors', 'motionblur' ),
    'singular_name'              => _x( 'Director', 'motionblur' ),
    'menu_name'                  => __( 'Directors', 'motionblur' ),
    'all_items'                  => __( 'All Items', 'motionblur' ),
    'parent_item'                => __( 'Parent Item', 'motionblur' ),
    'parent_item_colon'          => __( 'Parent Item:', 'motionblur' ),
    'new_item_name'              => __( 'New Item Name', 'motionblur' ),
    'add_new_item'               => __( 'Add New Item', 'motionblur' ),
    'edit_item'                  => __( 'Edit Item', 'motionblur' ),
    'update_item'                => __( 'Update Item', 'motionblur' ),
    'separate_items_with_commas' => __( 'Separate items with commas', 'motionblur' ),
    'search_items'               => __( 'Search Items', 'motionblur' ),
    'add_or_remove_items'        => __( 'Add or remove items', 'motionblur' ),
    'choose_from_most_used'      => __( 'Choose from the most used items', 'motionblur' ),
    'not_found'                  => __( 'Not Found', 'motionblur' ),
  );
  $args = array(
    'labels'                     => $labels,
    'hierarchical'               => true,
  'rewrite'                    => array('slug' => 'directors', 'with_front' => false),
    'public'                     => true,
    'show_ui'                    => true,
    'show_admin_column'          => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus'          => true,
    'show_tagcloud'              => true,
  );
  register_taxonomy( 'director_cat', array( 'projects' ), $args );

}

// Hook into the 'init' action
add_action( 'init', 'directors_cat', 0 );

/*--------------------------------------------------------------
  Registering Custom Taxonomy for Projects (directors)
--------------------------------------------------------------*/

function producers_cat() {

  $labels = array(
  'name'                       => _x( 'Producers', 'motionblur' ),
  'singular_name'              => _x( 'Producer', 'motionblur' ),
  'menu_name'                  => __( 'Producers', 'motionblur' ),
  'all_items'                  => __( 'All Items', 'motionblur' ),
  'parent_item'                => __( 'Parent Item', 'motionblur' ),
  'parent_item_colon'          => __( 'Parent Item:', 'motionblur' ),
  'new_item_name'              => __( 'New Item Name', 'motionblur' ),
  'add_new_item'               => __( 'Add New Item', 'motionblur' ),
  'edit_item'                  => __( 'Edit Item', 'motionblur' ),
  'update_item'                => __( 'Update Item', 'motionblur' ),
  'separate_items_with_commas' => __( 'Separate items with commas', 'motionblur' ),
  'search_items'               => __( 'Search Items', 'motionblur' ),
  'add_or_remove_items'        => __( 'Add or remove items', 'motionblur' ),
  'choose_from_most_used'      => __( 'Choose from the most used items', 'motionblur' ),
  'not_found'                  => __( 'Not Found', 'motionblur' ),
  );
  $args = array(
  'labels'                     => $labels,
  'hierarchical'               => true,
  'rewrite'                    => array('slug' => 'producers', 'with_front' => false),
  'public'                     => true,
  'show_ui'                    => true,
  'show_admin_column'          => true,
  'show_in_nav_menus'          => true,
  'show_tagcloud'              => true,
  );
  register_taxonomy( 'producer_cat', array( 'projects' ), $args );

}

// Hook into the 'init' action
add_action( 'init', 'producers_cat', 0 );
```

And the relevant bug report, that makes me think this a foreach loop issue:

```
`2017/01/11 12:01:14 [error] 5269#0: *13565 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/wordpress/wordpress/wp-includes/class-wp-post-type.php on line 599" while reading response header from upstream, client: 193.71.255.163, server: 10.40.16.118, request: "GET /directors/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "dev.motionblur.no", referrer: "http://dev.motionblur.no/`"
```

Comment: What does your `get_terms()` function return? Foreach only works with arrays and objects and will give a warning otherwise.

Comment: I managed to fix this. I had an error in the array in the projects post type for taxonomies. When I fixed that, and added an array to the line with the taxonomies, the issue resolved it self. Didn't solve my speed issue for the page it self, but this specific bug has been resolved.